# how to do Classification based on the correlation of multiple features for a Supervised scenario

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation

I have 2 features: 'Contact_Last_Name' and 'Account_Last_Name' based on which I want to Classify my data: 
The logic is that if the 2 features are same i.e. Contact_Last_Name is same as Account_Last_Name - then the result is 'Success' or else it is 'Denied'.
So. for example: if Contact_Last_Name is 'Johnson' and Account_Last_Name is 'Eigen' - the result is classified as 'Denied'. If both are equal say - 'Edison' - then the result is 'Success'.
How, can I have a Classification algorithm for this set of data?
[please note that usually we discard High Correlation columns but over here the correlation between columns seems to have the logic for Classification]

I have tried to use Decision Tree(C5.0) and Naive Bayes(naiveBayes) in R but both of these fail to Classify the dataset correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not a good use case for machine learning, because this can be done with just string match, but still if you want to give to a classification algorith, then create a table with values as 'Contact_Last_Name' and 'Account_Last_Name' and 'Result' and give it for decision tree and predict the third column.

Note that you partition your data for training and testing.

Comment: i already have a table and have fed it to Decision Tree. C5.0 fails to classify the data.

Comment: can u share the format ? how are we supposed to know what your table and content